# Uninstall windows technical preview

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

Recently I installed windows technical preview to test the features. So currently I have 2 operating system listed in boot menu. Windows 8.1 & Technical Preview( I installed Windows technical preview in other drive and that installation was not a update from previous version ).

So how can I remove the technical preview ? Initially I though to remove all the OS files from the harddrive.But I guess that it may cause some issues on booting. Could you please suggest me to remove the latest OS safely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use msconfig (under the boot tab)  or Easybcd to remove the boot entry for Windows Technical Preview. Then use a partition manager (diskpart, gparted, paragon, etc.) to delete the Technical Preview partition and then grow your Windows 8.1 partition to use the whole hard drive.